# Running unit tests seems to block io_service indefinitely

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, tcp, boost-asio

I have a class that uses `asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket` to connect to domain (`asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint`) and TCP sockets (`asio::ip::tcp::endpoint`).

To test that class I have a series of unit tests in a single file using the [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) framework.

I've suddenly come across a problem: when running tests they will get stuck. Passing `-DASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` to the compiler flags I can see that it gets stuck on `async_connect`. This does not happen if I comment all tests but one, no matter which. If I have two tests, no matter if they connect to domain or tcp sockets, or one of each, I get a blockage.

The output of Asio changes but this is an example:

```
$ tests/unit_tests
@asio|1478248907.301230|0*1|deadline_timer@0x7f96f1c07ad8.async_wait
@asio|1478248907.301276|0*2|resolver@0x7f96f1c07ac0.async_resolve
@asio|1478248907.301322|>1|ec=system:0
@asio|1478248907.301328|<1|
@asio|1478248907.302052|>2|ec=system:0,...
@asio|1478248907.302186|2*3|socket@0x7f96f1c07a20.async_connect
@asio|1478248907.302302|<2|
@asio|1478248907.302468|>3|ec=system:0
@asio|1478248907.302481|<3|
@asio|1478248907.302551|0*4|socket@0x7f96f1c07a20.async_send
@asio|1478248907.302611|>4|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=23
@asio|1478248907.302617|<4|
@asio|1478248907.302621|0*5|socket@0x7f96f1c07a20.async_receive(null_buffers)
@asio|1478248907.356478|>5|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=0
@asio|1478248907.356547|<5|
@asio|1478248907.356622|0|socket@0x7f96f1c07a20.close
@asio|1478248907.372967|0|deadline_timer@0x7f96f1c07ad8.cancel
@asio|1478248907.372981|0|resolver@0x7f96f1c07ac0.cancel
@asio|1478248907.373509|0*6|deadline_timer@0x7f96f1d00468.async_wait
@asio|1478248907.373526|0*7|resolver@0x7f96f1d00450.async_resolve
@asio|1478248907.374910|>7|ec=system:0,...
@asio|1478248907.374946|7*8|socket@0x7f96f1d003b0.async_connect
@asio|1478248907.375014|<7|
@asio|1478248907.375127|>8|ec=system:0
@asio|1478248907.375135|<8|
```

My question is: what is the problem with running unit tests that open and close connections? If this is a no-no, how do you write unit tests that use async_open?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?  The handler tracking output shows two `async_connect` operations as completing with success.  If one attaches a debugger, what is the traceback for the blocked thread?  Is `async_open` a user-defined higher-level operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be related to the way I was iterating through the output of a tcp::resolver.

Answer (score 0):

`io_service` has `run`, `run_one`, `poll` and `poll_one` methods which actually execute the completion handlers. Boost asio may have its own threads, but the thread state of those may not be correct to call your handlers. Hence, even in a unit test you must figure out which thread is going to call completion handlers.

Secondly, `run` runs to completion, and then returns. From your description (first test succeeds, second fails) it sounds like you did call `run` but did not `reset` and re-`run`the `io_service`.

Comment: The test doesn't fail, it just freezes. And can different instances of the same class share threads? Is there a single state shared among all uses of Asio?

Comment: @ruipacheco: whether your objects can share threads, we can't tell. Boost asio has its state in `io_service`, and again you decide whether you share one object or use multiple instances. `io_service.run()` can be called from multiple threads.